# Как получить массив элементов, находящихся внутри элемента div?

Tags: javascript, html

У меня есть функция `treatment(arr)`. Она принимает один параметр - массив элементов, находящихся внутри тега `<div id="list">...</div>`. Как мне получить такой массив?

```js
...
var arr = ...; // Массив
var button = document.getElementById('treatment');
button.onclick = function() {
    treatment(arr);
}
...
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title></title>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0px;">
  ...
  <div id="list">
      <div class="block">
          <h1 class="title">Item #1</h1>
          <div style="background: url('../img/icon/1.jpg');">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="block">
          <h1 class="title">Item #2</h1>
          <div style="background: url('../img/icon/2.jpg');">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="block">
          <h1 class="title">Item #3</h1>
          <div style="background: url('../img/icon/3.jpg');">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  ...
  <button id="treatment"></button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 Array.from(document.getElementById('list').children)
```

Comment: или `[...document.querySelectorAll("#list > *")]`

Comment: Да, так можно. С точки зрения производительности кода, достать элемент по id и получить доступ к свойству будет работать быстрее, чем бежать по всему DOM-дереву с помощью `querySelectorAll`